# Unknown provider when creating service - Angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to learn ionic & angular by making a basic texting app. so i started with the tabs template provided by ionic and am just tweaking things to figure out how everything works.

Anyway, I'm trying to pass the conversation ID from a table row to a conversation controller so that it can populate the view with the relevant information.

Here is my controller:

```
var baxter = angular.module('baxter');

baxter.controller('ConversationsCtrl', function($scope, 

conversationService) {
  $scope.conversations = conversationService.conversations;

  $scope.setCurrentConversation = function(convoID){
    conversationService.selectedConversation(convoID);
  }
});
```

The service:

```
var baxter = angular.module('baxter');

baxter.service('conversationService', function($http) {
  this.conversations = [
    { title: 'Jill Sanders', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Bobby Duck', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Boatie McBoatface', id: 3 },
    { title: 'Jesus Christ', id: 4 },
    { title: 'Tall Blonde', id: 5 },
    { title: 'Mom', id: 6 }
  ];

  this.selectedConversation = function(conversationID) {
    console.log(conversationID);
  }

  return this;
});
```

The error:

```
0     780569   error    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: conversationServiceProvider <- conversationService <- ConversationsCtrl
```

Comment: code looks correct.. only thing I can say is, do double check that `service.js` file has been loaded or not. by opening up developer console..

Comment: are you familiar with ionic? I'm not sure how to debug ionic since it uses the command line and an ios simulator

Comment: Can run ionic in browser also for debugging

Comment: just discovered the `ionic serve` command. it appears my files aren't loading

Comment: are you sure you have added the files to the `index.html` file?

Answer (score -1):

You are overwriting the variable `baxter` when you redeclare `var baxter` again. This will create a new instance and the previous declaration will be lost

In order not to worry about loading order and not using global variable to represent the module(s) I would suggest you not use `var` at all to reference modules and simply do:

```
angular.module('baxter').controller('ConversationsCtrl', ... ;

angular.module('baxter').service('conversationService'....
```

If multiple components are in one file you can also chain them:

```
angular.module('baxter')
     .controller('ConversationsCtrl',function(/* dependencies*/){

     })
     .service('conversationService'....
```

Reference: [John Papa Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y022)

Comment: I don't think so what you are pointed out is an issue with OP current problem... it good to have thing..